# What is QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS GetCount for use in Python script?

Tags: qgis, python, arcgis-desktop

I have a number of layers in **QGIS** that I would like to select attributes on, and get the feature count for, within a Python script.

In ArcGIS for Desktop I have been using **[SelectLayerByAttribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000071000000)** and **[GetCount](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000n7000000)**.

What is the QGIS equivalent?

Comment: Not sure what you mean: If you do a search in the attribute table, the number of matching features should be displayed in the attribute table window title.

Comment: In ArcGIS there is a simple workflow for selecting attributes of a feature class then printing the count of that feature class with Python.  I would like to automate this effort in QGIS.  The biggest thing is to not have to interact with the interace and print the results to an excel workbook or run the script outside of the interface.

Answer (score 3):

I guess these three lines should do:

```
l=iface.activeLayer() # or load the layer
l.setSubsetString("id=1") # your filter/query here
l.featureCount()
```

Comment: this works great

Comment: What is a method to use this on multiple layers?  I have had trouble understanding how to iterate through multiple layers in QGIS.

Comment: @GeoffreyWest Please open a new question (if this question hasn't been answered before)